# Detecting path of running jar file works- but BufferedWriter writes to jarfilename.jarmyfile.txt

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am really confused. I used the

```
String path = myclass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
                     .toString().replace("file:/", "") + "Myfile.txt"
```

(The `.replace("file:/", "")` is there or else it outputs file:/C:Insertpathhere)
to get the containing directory of the running jar. When I print this in the console, it prints C:/users/username/desktop/Myfile.txt. However, when I use a BufferedWriter with the same variable path, it outputs the file to C:/users/username/destop/Maze.jarMyfile.txt (Where maze.jar is the name of the jarfile).

I'm really stumped, can anyone help?

Full code:
(Where maz is a 2D character array of a generated map and genmaze is a 2D String array.)

```
   String path = myclass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString().replace("file:/", "") + "Myfile.txt"
    System.out.println(Values.mazegen);
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
        genmaze[i][j] = Character.toString(maz[i][j]);
        writer.write(maz[i][j]);
        System.out.print(maz[i][j]);
    }
    writer.newLine();
    System.out.println();
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to believe. PLease check again, and if you are sure this can be reproduced, post complete code for reproduction.

Comment: @laune I edited the post to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as it should:

```
    ProtectionDomain pd  = Y.class.getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource cs = pd.getCodeSource();
URL url = cs.getLocation(); 
System.out.println( "URL=" + url );
String path = url.toString().replace("file:", "") + "Myfile.txt";
```

and the file has the correct name.

Showing the correct URL, either of a directory (if I exec the .class) or of a jar, if I pack it into a jar.

**Please note** however, that I omitted the '/' from the replaced string. This would produce a relative pathname, and there's no telling what may happen then.